Data not splitting for Android MTU
In the onConnectionStateChange() , I am setting mtu to 30 bytes for android kotlin app.
However, the data that is being received in OnCharactersiticRead() is 340 bytes.
It shows that it called onMtuChanged, mtu is changed but the packets are not splitting?
I am working on Android 13
I tried logging and changing MTU from 30 to 512. The 340 bytes of data are received in value without any fragmenting.
